# How can I submit multi-page form in SvelteKit with Form Actions?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Normally, I store all the values of a form and send POST request to the server if it is a multipage form. But what if I have a form like this in my `+page.svelte`:

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import {enhance} from "$app/forms";

    let page: number = 1;
    const nextPage = () => {
        page++;
    }

    const prevPage = () => {
        page--;
    }

</script>
<form method="POST" use:enhance>
    {#if page === 1}
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="John Doe">
    {:else if page === 2}
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
    {:else if page === 3}
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
        <button type="submit">Register</button>
    {:else}
        <p>Thank you for registering!</p>
    {/if}
    <button type="button" on:click={prevPage} disabled={page === 1}>Previous</button>
    <button type="button" on:click={nextPage} disabled={page === 4}>Next</button>
</form>
```

and I want to send these Form data to server, inside of `+page.server.ts` so that the server logs all the value (I can work with those value later like authentication or something)

`+page.server.ts` File:

```js
export const actions = {
    default: async ({request}: any) => {
        const formData = await request.formData();

        const name = formData.get('name');
        const email = formData.get('email');
        const password = formData.get('password');

        console.log(name, email, password)
    }
}
```

Upon submitting, server is printing `null null ezpass`

> given that name = John, email = john@gmail.com, password = ezpass)

Is there any way of sending all the information to the +page.server.ts like this? Or I should do the other way, which is storing everything and make a POST request in the +page.svelte (I don't want to do that, I want to use form actions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `#if`, which removes the element completely, just hide the pages that are not the current one.

E.g.

```html
<div class="page" class:show={page === 1}>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="John Doe">
</div>
<div class="page" class:show={page === 2}>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
<div>
...

<style>
  .page { display: none; }
  .page.show { display: block; }
</style>
```